# Making the main scrollbar always visible

Tags: html, css, xhtml

What CSS is required to make the browser's vertical scrollbar remain visible when a user visits a web page (when the page hasn't enough content to trigger the scrollbar's activation)?

Comment: To prevent [jumping scrollbars in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220073/prevent-jumping-scrollbar-in-windows) there is a [better solution](https://aykevl.nl/2014/09/fix-jumping-scrollbar).

Answer (score 384, accepted):

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This makes the scrollbar always visible and only active when needed.

**Update**: If the above does not work then just using this may.

```
html {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what version of FF brought support for `overflow-y`? As it seems that `-moz-scrollbars-vertical` is deprecated in favor of the `overflow-y` property.

Comment: I think Internet Explorer 6.x+, Firefox 1.5+ if I remember correctly. I've been using the above code and it works in FF1.5-3.5.1 and IE6-8 for me.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to "page jumping" when certain pages on your site are too small to have a scroll bar and others are?  Or is this the "best practice"?  I'll have to admit, I don't see many pages out on the webs that don't take up a full page.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a best practice but, having scrollbars on all pages, and active only when necessary, to avoid page jumping is usually an acceptable solution.  I tend to prefer the constant scrollbar over the jump.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have added the exact css.

Comment: Can you show me the code, like in jsFiddle or something?

Comment: @Corv1nus Copy and paste the above code to any valid location in your CSS.

Comment: I updated it. -moz-scrollbars-vertical did not work in Chrome for me but, overflow-y: scroll did. Things change over 5 years.

Comment: For those (like me) who find styling `html` a bit *hack-y*, note that you can use the structural pseudo-selector `:root` instead of `html`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Comment: why the hell it doesn't work for me!? is this really a complete answer?

Comment: This question asks for the scrollbar to be visible at all times and this solution does not do this. -1

Comment: Hello, it works great with Macbook too, desktop computer but not with IPAD.Have you got a solution for IPAD , Iphone ?

Comment: I unfortunately do not, as I don't use Apple devices all that much.  Have you tried the other answers in the thread?  They may do what you need.  I wish I could be more helpful on that.

Comment: This solution does not work for macs, specifically due to the System Settings > Appearance > Show scroll bars setting when it is set to "When scrolling" (and/or "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad" when the trackpad is in use)

Answer (score 66):

Make sure overflow is set to "scroll" not "auto." **With that said**, in OS X Lion, overflow set to "scroll" behaves more like auto in that scrollbars will still only show when being used. So if any the solutions above don't appear to be working that might be why.

This is what you'll need to fix it:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

You can style it accordingly if you don't like the default.

Comment: This thing work! But how can you make it only on a specific div?

Comment: @Rich just like any other css element.   .yourdiv::-webkit-scrollbar {...}

Comment: @Kris Hi, thanks for the answer, here is the example of it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54667091/2637261

Comment: Why is this used `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: This is the only one that works. The ubiquitous `overflow-y:scroll;` does not work.

Comment: this should be selected answer. cause this is the only thing that works.

Answer (score 37):

Things have changed in the last years. The answers above are not valid in all cases any more. Apple is pushing [disappearing scrollbars](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/apple_granted_patent_for_disappearing_scrollbar) everywhere. Safari, Chrome and even Firefox on MacOs (and iOs) only show scrollbars when actually scrolling — I don't know about current Windows/IE. However there are non-standard ways to style [scroll bars](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) on Webkit (IE dropped that a long time ago).

Comment: but it degrades gracefully right on those new ones ?

Comment: Thanks for this excellent point on the disappearing scrollbars. For me the reason to keep the scrollbar visible was to avoid that slight but very noticeable and very annoying jerk as content changes from having scroll to not. With the disappearing scrollbars, they dont jerk the body when they show and hide so its ok for me. But thanks for this excellent point.

Comment: From a UX standpoint, most times we want the scrollbar visible. Per the current trend, If a scrollbar is not visible, it is additional step to have to "try out" a visible list for more in the list. An additional visual clue that the drop down or list has more items in it is not needed if people see a scrollbar.

Answer (score 28):

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Unfortunately, Opera 9.64 seems to ignore that CSS declaration when applied to `HTML` or `BODY`, although it works for other block-level elements like `DIV`.

Answer (score 15):

`body { height:101%; }` will "crop" larger pages.

Instead, I use:

```
body { min-height:101%; }
```

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago and it already has an accepted answer. Your answer does not provide a better answer than the already accepted answer.

Comment: This answer does actually provide additional information not provided in the other answers.

Answer (score 14):

```
html {height: 101%;}
```

I use **this cross browsers solution** *(note: I always use DOCTYPE declaration in 1st line, I don't know if it works in quirksmode, never tested it*).

This will **always show an ACTIVE vertical scroll bar** in every page, vertical scrollbar will be scrollable only of few pixels.

When page contents is **shorter** than browser's visible area (view port) you will still see the vertical scrollbar active, and it will be scrollable only of few pixels.

In case you are obsessed with CSS validation (I'm obesessed only with HTML validation) by using this solution your CSS code would also validate for W3C because you are not using non standard CSS attributes like `-moz-scrollbars-vertical`

Comment: Elegant solution

Comment: Not an elegant solution, having it scrollable by only a few pixels is annoying.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is to set the width of the html element to 100vw. On many if not most browsers, this negates the effect of scrollbars on the width.

```
html { width: 100vw; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work by adding it to the body tag. Was nicer for me because I don't have anything on the html element.

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 101% is my solution to the problem.
You pages will no longer 'flick' when switching between ones that exceed the viewport height and ones that do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
    min-height: 101vh; 
}
```

works the best for me

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
html {
    margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Then I don't have to look at the ugly greyed out scrollbar when it's not needed.

Comment: The question asks for it to always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
html { height:initial!important; }
```

You may not need the !important - depends on what CSS is in place.