# How can I make my site in the center of the page

Tags: css

I made a CSS template
And I want to make it in the center of the page 
when I open the browser 
it appears on the left of the page
any help please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `margin:auto` with specified `width` like this:

```
#wrapper{
  margin:auto;
  width:1000px;  /* adjust width */
}
```

Where `#wrapper` is supposed to be the main container element on your page.

Comment: there's a common gotcha with this, making your centered div jump a few pixels to the left between pages depending on whether scrollbars are active or not. a common solution is given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/html-css-making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible/1202542#1202542

Comment: It's worth noting that this will affect the top and bottom margins of `#wrapper` as well.

Answer (score 2):

To get this centered properly, the wrapper needs to have a set width and we need to set the left and right margins to auto.

```
#wrapper {
width: 960px; /* set to width of content */
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Sarfraz was on the right page, but there is no reason to set the top and bottom margins to auto. We should only affect the properties that are necessary to get the result we want.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will affect the top and bottom margins of `#wrapper` as well.

Comment: @Alison, I doubt that Maged has margins currently set at either the top or the bottom of the #wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

user

```
body{
  margin:0 auto;
}
or top root parent id

#parentid{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The body tag defaults to 100% width. Therefore, setting the left and right margins to auto will have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

My method is slightly different to those already here so here's my suggestion.

```
div#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
}
```

Where #wrapper is a div containing the main content of your site.

margin-left should equal whatever half of your width is.

Comment: Is there any advantage to this solution over `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;`?

Comment: This is a good solution for centering something vertically, but it seems kind of unnecessary to take the entire wrapper out of the standard flow by positioning it absolutely. Also, there are much simpler solutions that aren't hacks.

Comment: RE: Brian - If you didn't want to take it out of the flow, you could use position: relative; Then anything that followed the div would appear where it should. It's already quite simple, so I wouldn't define it as a hack.

RE: Alison - I don't think there is an advantage / disadvantage in using either. This is just the way I've always done it, and it always worked for me.

Comment: @diggersworld at the risk of sounding rude, this solution doesn't seem elegant to me

Comment: @diggersworld, this is unnecessary all the way around. Why would I do all of this when I could do it with 2 styles, width and margin?

Comment: @Brian, you don't have to do it this way, it was just an alternate suggestion. Semantically he wants to position his wrapper in the centre of the page, so I use the position attribute to highlight that. Margin is part of the box model. Technically they work in a different way, visually they work the same. Like I said it's just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Specify left and right margins as `auto` and set a width for the body:

```
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 780px;
}
```

I chose 780px for the width, but you could put whatever you want.  Specifying in other units (e.g. em, %) should work too.