# How to always show the vertical scrollbar in a browser?

Tags: html, css, browser

I want to always show vertical scrollbar in my webpage. Is it possible using javascript? I think it is possible using javascript or jQuery. I want vertical scrollbar whether there is enough content to show or not.

thanks.

Comment: you gotta ask these things to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

jQuery shouldn't be required. You could try adding the CSS:

```
body    {overflow-y:scroll;}
```

This works across the latest browsers, even IE6.

Comment: I believe the `overflow-x`and `overflow-x` have given me some pains in the past.

Comment: I think this will display the scrollbar only when there is overflow. To display the scrollbar always try

body {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 101%;
}

Comment: You have this round the wrong way. If you set the overflow:auto then the scroll bars show if necessary. overflow:scroll always shows the scrollbars. If the content isn't long enough then the scrollbars are greyed out.

Comment: If I want only two elements to be displayed in HTML select and still want vertical scrollbar then overflow-y:scroll; does not work.

Comment: This works for me, but I also had to add `!important` so that the Bootstrap modals I'm using won't hide the scrollbar.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome and Safari and it does not work for me in either. The scroll bar only appears once I try to scroll to see more content. Nothing I do seems to make any difference.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be enough to always show the scrollbar

Answer (score 58):

**Just a note:** In OS X Lion, overflow set to "scroll" behaves more like auto in that scrollbars will only show when being used. They will disappear when not in use. So if any the solutions above don't appear to be working that might be why.

This is what you'll need to fix it:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

You can style it accordingly.

Comment: Indeed it's [mac os specific](https://support.vagaro.com/hc/en-us/articles/204347160-Disable-Disappearing-Scroll-Bars-Mac)

Answer (score 16):

Just use CSS.

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Note the OP is looking to show only the *vertical* scrollbar. The `overflow` property in this case means the horizontal scrollbar would also be shown. You should use `overflow-y` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Tried to do the solution with:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But I ended up with two scrollbars in Firefox in this case. So I recommend to use it on the html element like this:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

set the [`overflow` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflow.asp) of a containing `div` to `scroll`.

Answer (score 3):

try calling a function on the onload method of your body tag and in that function change the style of body like this document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll'; also you might need to set the width of your html as this will show horizontal scroll bars as well

your html file will look something like this

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showscroll() {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showscroll()">
```

Comment: Well, OP asked for a Javascript solution, but that doesn't mean that's what he needs. This is a very bad solution to change a style. This is what CSS is for: Cascaded **Style** Sheets. In CSS it's just a single line, like the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Nothing to show here
```

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

/* Of course you can style it even more */
```

```html
<h1 style="margin: 0;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Scroll</h1>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly this code works to solve the problem in the question?

Comment: Hello, it works great with Macbook too, desktop computer but not with IPAD.Have you got a solution for IPAD , Iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method. This will not only provide scrollbar container, but will also show the scrollbar even if content isnt enough (as per your requirement). Would also work on Iphone, and android devices as well..

```
<style>
    .scrollholder {
        position: relative;
        width: 310px; height: 350px;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function isTouchDevice() {
        try {
            document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function touchScroll(id) {
        if (isTouchDevice()) { //if touch events exist...
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            var scrollStartPos = 0;

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
                scrollStartPos = this.scrollTop + event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
                this.scrollTop = scrollStartPos - event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="touchScroll('scrollMe')">

    <!-- title -->
    <!-- <div class="title" onselectstart="return false">Alarms</div> -->
    <div class="scrollholder" id="scrollMe">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class to the div you want to be scrollable.

**overflow-x: hidden;** hides the horizantal scrollbar.
While **overflow-y: scroll;** allows you to scroll vertically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.scroll {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scroll"><h1> DATA </h1></div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me. The latter (property *background*) sets the scroll bar to be always visible and also accepts further customization.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

If the scroll appears/is needed, then, it is going to last forever.

Answer (score -2):

I have been doing it this way:

```
.element {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Painfully simple I know...