# html margin issue - "Shaking" Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

Im working on a Website and everything is ok, except my webside is "shaking". (I'm using chrome)
The margin of my main Container is changing on some sides and i have no idea why. They have the same html code, it must have something to do with the content in the main div-container

My Website: www.anitalernt.de

http://www.anitalernt.de/about-us.html is a bit more to the left and http://www.anitalernt.de/index.html after getting a task (just click some buttons) also.

Has someone a idea?

Comment: It looks like the scrollbar on http://www.anitalernt.de/about-us.html is causing this.

Answer (score 12):

Always display the scrollbar

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

See:

[Always show browser scrollbar to prevent page jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582555/always-show-browser-scrollbar-to-prevent-page-jumping)

[How to always show the vertical scrollbar in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050076/how-to-always-show-the-vertical-scrollbar-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 5):

You could add

```
html{ overflow-y: scroll;}
```

to your css.

Places a permanent (but sometimes empty) scroll bar on the window

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely caused by the scrollbar appearing, which reduces the viewable area of the browser window and may adjust the contents accordingly.

There are a couple possible workarounds:

You could extend the length of the adjusted web-page so that the content (post-adjustment) also runs "below the fold"

Alternatively, you could encase everything in an absolute positioned DIV which won't "shake" when the viewable area contracts on the scrollbar's appearance.

Or -- depending on your specific content -- you could disable the scrollbar.  Although this last workaround is only advisable in very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

seems to resolve this without having to add a dummy scrollbar :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of `jQuery` scroll where I was checking the scroll value and using that. I fixed my navigation bar by using `addClass` and `removeClass`, adding class was not working because I did not use `!important` in `CSS` class.