# Angular UI bootstrap accordian - expand creates scrollbar and page "jump"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the angular ui bootstrap accordian. Everything works great except when I expand an accordian section that is big enough to cause the browser to show a scrollbar for the page, the whole page jolts to the left by the amount of the width of the scrollbar. When the accordian is small enough that a scrollbar isn't needed, the page jolts back to the original size.

I'm not sure what to do about this...does this require a hack, or is there some elegant solution using accordian settings or bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only solution is to always show the scrollbar

[How to always show the vertical scrollbar in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050076/how-to-always-show-the-vertical-scrollbar-in-a-browser)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.