# Can't figure this out, website is 'jumping'

Tags: css, hyperlink

I hope someone can help me with this, I've been searching in my CSS whats wrong but can't figure it out. 
If you look at this website: http://viversa.nl/v2/index.html , and check out the pages, you'll notice some jumping between sites. You'll notice it specially if you click from 'Projecten' to 'People' and back.
It seems "HOME" and "PROJECTEN" are the same, with both a good layout. Then the other pages: "OVER ONS", "PEOPLE", "CONTACT" and "SITEMAP" have a different layout together aswell. I can't figure out whats wrong and how come its jumping, since I simple copied the menu + logo + css, to make a new page over and over. 
Hope someone can help me out with this!
Thanks!

Sincerely, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

This "jumping" is caused by the Scrollbar beeing present on some pages and not beeing present on some other pages. The easiest way is to make sure, that there will always be a scrollbar.

You can get some tips how to do that here: [HTML/CSS: Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/html-css-making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

Comment: You sir, are my hero!!! :) That was the problem and the solution. Pfew, and I was struggling two days with this problem haha!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Heroes always like when theire answers are being accepted ;-)