# Prevent Screen flicker when scrollbars appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript event that extends the height of the current page so the scrollbar appear. This causes the screen to jump a bit (to the left), as it is compensating for the scrollbars, which seems distracting and annoying. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: This is not a duplicate! "Making the main scrollbar always visible" is **ONE** possible solution to this question (**actually not**, he asks "when scrollbars appears" not "how to prevent it from disappearing" so that doesn't really answer), but could we also search for other solutions? Add a margin-right to the html element if it is not scrolling? (yea, but what size?) Make the body or html element absolutely positioned to the left so it doesn't move? This is an unanswered question, maybe one with no solution, but definitely **not** a duplicate!

Answer (score 7):

html { margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }
A bit late but found this fix [here](https://css-tricks.com/elegant-fix-jumping-scrollbar-issue/).

Answer (score 2):

You could force the body (or div or whatever) to display the scroll bar at all times.

Here's a link to another SO answer with the requisite HTML:
[Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)