# Why there is no scroll bar in any browser?

Tags: html, css, yii

My own page doesn't have a scroll bar, no matter what I do, minimize or zoom in/out. It just doesn't appear, I've tried FF, Chrome and IE: all no. Other internet pages are fine. Here is the body element and css:

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="page">
```

The CSS is like:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #555;
    font: normal 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#page
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #C9E0ED;
}
```

PS: I'm using YII framework.

UPDATE:

IT seems YII has some default css settings, in screen.css the div `container` is mentioned three times as follows:

```
 .container {width:1250px;margin:0 auto;}
 .container:after 
 {content:"\0020";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;}

.container {display:block;}
```

I changed `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:scroll`but still didn't work.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle which reproduces this? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It seems like you dont show all you HTML code... Does the div have a closing tag </div>?

Comment: When using overflow you should also specify element height. Did you try removing that property?

Comment: Are you using a mac? >_< - You could be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855590/how-can-i-prevent-scroll-bars-from-being-hidden-for-os-x-trackpad-users-in-webki).

Comment: @Webking Yes, this is part of the code, The div pairs are all fine.

Comment: @Wezly no I'm not using a mac , thanks.  @SOReader @Happy Patrick  I added the height and width properties, `width: 80px; height: 80px` still no scroll bar.

Comment: Wild guess, did somewhere else in your code reset css like this `body{overflow:OTHERVALUE !important}`?

Comment: @lastr2d2  Good guess, I searched and found something might reset the css, see my update.. still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see a scroll you'll have to define a height and or width in which creates a scroll. Not being able to see if you have content or what your mark-up is like -- declaring at the HTML or body tag will do the trick.

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #555;
    font: normal 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 1000px; // toggle
    width: 100% // toggle

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Evelyn1986 
Force some width and it'll come up.
Try `width:805px;
     overflow:auto;`
Then just have some content, that's 'big'

Comment: There is no need to force any width. OP has already set `overflow:scroll` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Syntax

Comment: Forcing width is just for test purposes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

please add height on body tag..and add content more than what value you are give on height property....

```
body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #555;
font: normal 10pt Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
background: #EFEFEF;
overflow: scroll;
height:100px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/rVd4M/