# scrollbar not visible js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm having trouble showing my scrollbar in a website. When I load the screen it's no where to be found. But when I open inspector or when I resize my webbrowser size a bit smaller it suddenly appears where it should..

When reloading the resized webbrowser the scrollbar is yet again, no where to be found. But when I resize my webbrowser size a bit bigger it suddenly appears again.

The page contains a shortcode which brings up a photo gallery. So I need it to have a scrollbar to look at the bottom photo's.

Here is the link: http://www.mikevandermeij.nl/foto-gallerij/

Comment: Your div with class jspVerticalBar isn't loading from the start, only after a resize. So there's something wrong in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible) for making a scrollbar on a page always visible. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for the css overflow property. If you set overflow to auto it should generate a scrollbar if the div's content exceeds its size.