# Phonegap Scrollbar

Tags: cordova, scrollbar, phonegap-plugins

Hi i am trying to get the scrollbar to appear on a phonegap app, but it just won't appear. I have read all the threads there are.

Set these in the CSS stylesheet. I have already read on the thread that you can't set them? Thanks for your time

```
scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 10px !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px !important;

}
scrollbar:vertical {
   width: 5px !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
     width: 5px !important;
}
scrollbar:horizontal {
  height: 2px !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
     height: 2px !important;
}

scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#42c0fb !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
     border: 2px solid blue; 
     background-color:blue;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color:#42c0fb !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;

}
scrollbar-track {
   border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: did you try to following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1202542/2765346
it makes the scrollbar always visible

Comment: Hi i just tried that as well but it still doesnt appear.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this myself by using `Webkit` scrollbar CSS that only gets applied on Android. I add the android-scroll-bar class to the page on Android by using

`$('html').addClass('android-scroll-bar');`

Here is the necessary CSS:

```
.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border-radius: 10px;}

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-radius: 10px; background: rgb(169,169,169); }

.android-scroll-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgb(128,128,128); }
```

And for display scrollbar, you have to install Cordova crosswalk plugin.
And for PhoneGap, there may be crosswalk plugin also.

Comment: I just like to mention, because it can be easily overlooked, but in particular the crosswalk plugin was what did the trick for me.