# Scrollbar fades out when not in use. This should not happen

Tags: javascript, html

I want the scrollbar to be always visible to allow the user to understand that there is extra content. Currently the scrollbar fades out if not in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

Comment: no still in mac os its hidden when not in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

I think the answer you're looking for is found here, but for simpliicty:

```
 html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If this does not work, take off the top overflow so you're left with just

```
  html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS this is set at the system level, and shouldn't be forced by the site

Comment: if i want to force it on a website , can i do that ?