# Force scrollbar to always be visible on iphone Chrome (CSS)

Tags: css, mobile-website

I have a modal and its content should overflow and scroll. I want the scroll bar to always be visible because some of my users have told me they didn't realize they could scroll for more information.

Unfortunately, on iPhone Chrome, nothing I've tried has worked. How can I use CSS to make the vertical scroll bar permanently visible?

Current CSS (this code appears to work on Chrome's inspect mobile view, but it doesn't work in real life):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
  width: 12px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;  
  background-color: #ffffff; 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
}
```

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible

Comment: @Thisanthan Is there a specific answer in that post that helps? I've tried most of the stuff in there, but nothing has worked so far. It seems like a lot of the solutions on StackOverflow worked until about 2017, but don't work any more.