# CSS scrolling with top overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make div elements containing short text strings appear (using JS) in the middle of a blank page, with new elements always centered and older elements moving upwards (similar to what a console or terminal session would look like). Elements that disappear at the top of the page should be viewed by scrolling upwards (i.e. back in time).

The following code works but scroll bars don't appear. Why is that?

HTML

```css
#wordlist {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

.word {
  // Just font and color
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wordlist">
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word" id="current">whatever</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Add a `max-height` to the `div`. This will make sure that the height of the `div` shouldn't go beyond the `max-height`. Then, add `overflow: auto`. This will make sure that when the height goes beyond the `max-height`, scrollbars should appear.

`overflow: auto;` works for both `width` and `height`. If you want to be specify, you can always go for `overflow-y: auto;`.

Also, I forgot to mention that `max-height` will not unnecessarily maintain a fixed height if the children are less.

```css
#wordlist {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

.word {
  // Just font and color
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wordlist">
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word" id="current">whatever</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `max-height` made it work, and BTW it works also if I keep the original declaration of `overflow: scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `overflow: auto`

Sample of this can be found here
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hide-reveal-a-sticky-header-on-scroll-with-javascript--cms-33756

Answer (score 0):

See [Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

might fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't change the behaviour (either by adding it or replacing the above `overflow` value).

Answer (score 0):

Just add height to your `#wordlist` div.

Comment: I tried that. This indeed adds the scrollbar as expected but the problem with adding height (either a percentage or a pixel value) is that at the beginning (when the `#wordlist` div is empty), the inserted `.word` divs are no longer aligned to the bottom of of the containing div, but to the top instead. Only when the container div is full and the scrollbar appears do the new elements appear where they should (i.e. at the bottom of the container and on the center of the page).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the 'height' CSS property. Mentioning an appropriate pixel value as height, and implementing 'scrollTop()' method on the id of the container upto its height will help in showing the scrollbar at the bottom.

```js
$("#wordlist").scrollTop($('#wordlist').height())
```

```css
#wordlist {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

.word {
  // Just font and color
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="wordlist">
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word">whatever</div>
    <div class="word" id="current">Latest Value</div>
  </div>
</body>
```